# Load and display .rds files with rshiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm currently building a rshiny app to process some calculation on data. I'm facing some problems with the loading and the displaying of my data. The data format is .rds. I'm just trying to load it through the interface and displaying it as a table. 
The loading seems to be ok but either I've no table displayed or I only have informations about the file like "name", "size", "type", "datapath".

Here's the code :

**ui**

```
fluidPage(

# Copy the line below to make a file upload manager
fileInput("file", label = h3("File input")),

hr(),
fluidRow(column(4, dataTableOutput("value")))

)
```

**server**

```
function(input, output) {

# You can access the value of the widget with input$file, e.g.


output$value <- renderDataTable({
input$file
})

}
```

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You still need to read the file in...e.g. `out <- readRDS(input$file)`

Comment: In the example, you still have to use a function to read the file https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/fileInput.html.  Just like @MDEWITT said

Answer (score 1):

It might be as simple as the following, if I understand the question:

```
function(input, output) {

# You can access the value of the widget with input$file, e.g.


output$value <- renderDataTable({
out <- readRDS(input$file)
out
})

}
```

You still have to read in the RDS file that you are loading as an input. Then once you have read it in, then it can be rendered as a table.

Comment: I was searching on that way, it makes sense to read the file before displaying it. I've tried your suggestion but now I've got an Error : bad'fil' argument. The problem might be in the ui part ?

Comment: **EDIT :**
I've reach my goal by copy paste the example that you gave me and replace read.csv by readRDS and delete the second argument ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

So I had a similar problem to you, but didn't have any luck with the solution posted by @MDEWITT. After some digging around, I found the answer on the [fileInput](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/fileInput.html) documentation page. For me the issue seemed to be that just trying to load `input$file` still gave the error. Looking at the documentation, the example posted saved the `input$file` to another variable and then referenced a `datapath` within it. Modifying my code to the following worked perfectly:

```
server <- function(input, output) { 
    output$fullDataTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
        dataFile <- input$loadFile
        if(is.null(dataFile)) {
            return()
        } else {
            readRDS(dataFile$datapath)
        }
    })
}
```